# Making complex query even more complex (need to get full term path instead of one level)

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query to retrieve product variant ids and corresponding taxonomy term (of the vocabulary Catalog).

There

1. **field_data_field_products** contains field_products_product_id (product variant) and corresponding entity_id (product, i.e. some field_products_product_id can have same entity_id)
2. **taxonomy_term_data** contains tid (term id) and name (term name)
3. **field_data_field_catalog** contains field_catalog_tid (id of the term) and entity_id (product)
4. **taxonomy_term_hierarchy** contains tid (term id) and parent (parent term tid)

```sql
SELECT
  field_data_field_products.field_products_product_id AS p1,
  taxonomy_term_data.name AS p2
FROM taxonomy_term_data
INNER JOIN field_data_field_catalog
  ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_catalog.field_catalog_tid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_products
  ON field_data_field_catalog.entity_id = field_data_field_products.entity_id
```

My query (though maybe not optimized) retrieves product variant ids and corresponding taxonomy term.

But I have two-level term hierarchy. So, the terms I get are of level 2. I want to get instead of it 'term_level_1/term_level_2' combination. How can I do this? Is it possible in one query?

Comment: Join the table twice?

Comment: Isn't it right? It works.

Comment: Who knows? Without seeing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET, I don't really see how we're supposed to help. That said, I find this kind of naming policy tiresome, so it may be for others to answer this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want output, and without tables I can't test it, but this should give you something to base your code on:-

```
SELECT
  field_data_field_products.field_products_product_id AS p1,
  taxonomy_term_data.name AS p2
  c.field_products_product_id AS p1,
  a.name AS p2
FROM taxonomy_term_data
INNER JOIN field_data_field_catalog
  ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_catalog.field_catalog_tid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_products
  ON field_data_field_catalog.entity_id = field_data_field_products.entity_id
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy
ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = taxonomy_term_hierarchy.tid
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data a
ON a.tid = taxonomy_term_hierarchy.parent
INNER JOIN field_data_field_catalog b
  ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = b.field_catalog_tid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_products c
  ON b.entity_id = c.entity_id
```

Comment: Thanks! 6 inner joins finally

Comment: No problems. You can join tables against themselves / use the same table multiple times in a query but you need to give the tables (or at least one use of them) an alias name so mysql knows which one you are referring to.